# Which apps cannot be disabled (without root)?

Tags: applications, disable-app

I need to know more about disabling built-in apps. Some apps can be disabled, but there are some which has "disable" button disabled. 
Is there any way how to find out which apps cannot be disabled? (I know that disabling some of them (e.g. settings) doesn't make sense, but some apps look OK for disabling and it is not possible for them too). Is there some other problem with disabling them? (I heard that some of them enable themselves with restart of phone).

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps with Disable button disabled is the only way to identify they are critical to run the system without any issue and they can not be disabled. There are few services like google play services(in case of google apps), system server which needs to be run always to run the system smoothly. Finally, disabled apps will not be enabled and run until user manually enables them.

Comment: It is possible that devices producers have possibility to forbid Disabling of apps even when it is not necessary for smooth run?

Comment: @TGar probably, but I think it is an app property, not a device property. App devs decide if their app should be able to disable.

Comment: @TGar yes it is possible as system apps were controlled by them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot disable "system apps". A layman definition of system apps can be ones those are installed when you install the ROM.

there can be a few in custom ROMs and UIs that companies provide because they think it is useful.

if you have something like ESExplorer, I think you can see which apps are system apps and which are user apps.